# Unable to space out markers in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I have an image with white spots all over them. Now, I want to put a marker on each spot based on certain coordinates and checks. Now my problem is, i don't want to cluster too many markers on one particular "blob" of white spots that takes up more than a pixel. My work around is to check if my previous marker location and my current are within proximity. However, this causes a lot of independent white blobs to be missed due to close proximity even if it's not necessarily just one blob.

Here is my current code:

```
a = find(overlap == 1); %overlap is a 1040 by 1392 binary matrix
prev_coord = [1 1];

for i=1:size(a)
    c = mod(a(i), 1040);
    r = floor(a(i)/1040);
    X = [prev_coord; r c];
    if(pdist(X, 'euclidean') > prox)      
       if(img(r, c) > 1)
           gray = insertMarker(gray, [r c], 'x', 'color', 'red', 'size', 15); 
       else
           gray = insertMarker(gray, [r c], 'x', 'color', 'white', 'size', 15);      
       end
    end
    prev_coord = [r c];
end
```

When `prox` equals a very small number like 50, my image looks like this:
[image]

However, when `prox` is a large number like 120, it looks like this:
[image]

Any ideas on how to work around this?

Comment: I would check if 2 coordinates are belong to a blob using connected components methods, such as `bwlabel`, it's more robust than the distance between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using [morphological operations](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html):

```
A = round(overlap./max(overlap(:))) % turn original image into binary image.
A = imfill(A,'holes'); % fill holes in blobs
A = bwmorph(A,'shrink',Inf) % reduce each blob to a single point
```

Then you can place a marker on each pixel where `A==1`.

Comment: That was a terrific solution!

Comment: Do you have a better suggestion for the title of this post? I know many people who have had the same problem and it might be more useful if this question's title was better worded.

Comment: How about this: "Finding the centres of white spots in an image"? That's at least exactly what my code does. But it does not mention the markers. Maybe "Placing markers at the centres of white spots in an image"? A bit unwieldy but describes the problem and also kinda works as a tag cloud.